# TSQL having statement from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 2 tables that I am working with at the moment.

Table 1 `empTable`

Table 2 `empowermentSubmissions`

In my `empTable` there are a lot of fields but the ones I am concerned about is `empID` and `supEmpID`.

`EmpID` is the ID of the employee and `SupEmpID` is the ID of the supervisor.

```
SELECT   TOP 5 count(A.[nomineeEmpID]) as totalSubmissions,
                 A.[nomineeEmpID],
                 B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] as supName,
                 B.[ntid] as supNTID,
                 (
                    SELECT count(SupEmpID) as totalTeammates FROM EmpTable WHERE SupEmpID = A.[nomineeEmpID]
                 )
        FROM     empowermentSubmissions as A
        JOIN empTable as B
        ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[EmpID]
        GROUP BY nomineeEmpID, B.[FirstName], B.[Lastname], B.[ntid]
        HAVING count(SupEmpID) > 0
        ORDER BY totalSubmissions desc
        FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
```

I am trying to pull the top 5 stats from the submissionsTable for supervisors. In order to do this, I need to look through the emmployeeTable and find any employees that have their `EmpID` in the `SupEmpID` field. That would mean that some one reports to that employee making them a supervisor.

You can see my intentions above but it is not working correctly. I don't think the having clause can use the data from the sub query.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with the new having statement:

```
SELECT   TOP 5 count(A.[nomineeEmpID]) as totalSubmissions,
                 A.[nomineeEmpID],
                 B.[FirstName] + ' ' + B.[LastName] as supName,
                 B.[ntid] as supNTID
        FROM     empowermentSubmissions as A
        JOIN empTable as B
        ON A.[nomineeEmpID] = B.[EmpID]
        GROUP BY nomineeEmpID, B.[FirstName], B.[Lastname], B.[ntid], SupEmpID
        HAVING (SELECT count(SupEmpID) as totalTeammates FROM EmpTable WHERE SupEmpID = A.[nomineeEmpID]) > 0
        ORDER BY totalSubmissions desc
        FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root')
```